# Django & webapp living together on GAE?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Is it possible to have both frameworks available?
So that I could have

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(render_to_string('some.template'))
```

and

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

running mapped to different URLs?

EDIT:
The question basically boils down to how do I implement

```
urlpatterns = [
               # webapp-style handler
               (r'/webapp', views.MainPage),
               # django
               (r'/django', views.hello),
              ]
```

Comment: I would add to this that if you want to use the webapp framework, go into google/appengine/ext/webapp and check it out, because it overlaps with django's template functionality. 

I'm also more into defining url patterns from within a python module compared to the app.yaml for a couple of reasons (i can use a url() method in templates and pass variable kwargs to my RequestHandler classes). So Nick's advice is good, but there's a bunch of ways to go about it. 

Take a look at some of the open source GAE projects out there, and you'll see a range of approaches.

Comment: Thanks, jamtoday.
What projects would you suggest to look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly - as long as you're not using 0.9.6 in one sub-app and 1.0 (via the use_library call) in the other. Just map URL regular expressions to separate handlers in app.yaml and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Django is just a set of libraries, so in one sense, you can definitely run it on Google App Engine (or any WSGI-compatible web container). However, it won't work if you try to freely mix the two frameworks, as each expects to have total control of the request/response cycle, and has different abstractions for the request lifecycle, session management, etc.

You *can* use Django to code GAE applications by writing your own WSGI handler module. See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html) for a basic rundown on how to have a single Django app answer all requests for your GAE instance.

Mixing the two within a single request isn't going to work, though you *could* use the Django templating library (or a clone like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)) if you just want the front-end to borrow from Django's syntax. Also, you should be able to set up Google app handlers and Django endpoints under different URLs by extending the WSGI dispatcher in the above article. However, I would question whether trying to support two entirely different web frameworks for a single site was really worth the extra complexity.

Comment: Good answer.  Just one note though..GAE already uses Django's templating lib: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In fact, if you go to the GAE site the "getting started" tutorial shows exactly that! Both libraries are built in, so it's incredibly easy to get up and going with it.

[Google App Engine: Getting Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/)